# The Intersection of Every Set in a Family of Sets is the Largest Set Contained in the Family?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following theorem concerning a nonempty family of sets $\mathscr{A}$.

Let $B$ be a set and $\cap_{X \in \mathscr{A}} X \subseteq A$ for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$. If $B \subseteq X$ for all $X \in \mathscr{A}$, then $B \subseteq \cap_{X \in \mathscr{A}} X$.

The author claims that this theorem says that $\cap_{X \in \mathscr{A}} X$ is the largest set contained in all the sets in $\mathscr{A}$. But how is it true, and is it only true if we must have the condition that $B \subseteq X$ for all $X \in \mathscr{A}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis "and $\cap_{X \in \mathscr{A}} X \subseteq A$ for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$" is redundant -- it's always true.

Intersection of a family of sets, or of finitely many sets, gives the greatest lower bound with respect to set inclusion.

The condition on $B$ says: for all $X \in \mathscr{A}$, $B \subseteq X$ – that is,

> for all $X \in \mathscr{A}$, for all $x \in B$, $x \in X$.

The conclusion says: for all $x \in B$, $x \in \cap_{X \in \mathscr{A}}X$ – which is to say,

> for all $x \in B$, for all $X \in \mathscr{A}$, $x \in X$.

Once you expand the definition of the term $\cap_{X \in \mathscr{A}}X$, as above, you can see that the statement is far from deep – it's useful, but trivial.